# How can I change variable value from console in a file on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am on a website, and on this website there is a file named "Away.js". Which starts:

```
var S = require('core/Storage');
var I = require('core/InputParser');
module.exports = function () { var tAfk;
```

And everything else is in the function().
I need somehow to change the value of tAfk, is that even possible?
I don't want to change the original value in their file, but to write a script which will be changing it for me all the time.

Comment: You are not able to do that, unless the code sets the variable to something that is global, and not local.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: You can change it locally using debugger tools. It won't change the original file of course.

Comment: You probably want something like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)...